# Leave-one-out cross validation with bayesian networks - R

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, bayesian-network

I have a dataset with 1000 rows and 10 columns and s/n values.
The head of the data :

```
>head(datos)
      lluvia nieve granizo tormenta niebla rocio escarcha nieveSuelo neblina viento
    1      s     n       n        n      n     n        n          n       n      s
    2      s     n       n        n      n     n        n          n       n      s
    3      s     n       n        s      n     n        n          n       n      s
    4      s     n       n        n      n     n        n          n       n      s
    5      s     n       s        s      n     n        n          n       n      s
    6      s     n       s        s      n     n        n          n       n      s
```

Here is the *bayesian network with high climbing learned* :

```
>library(bnlearn)
>myHc <- hc(datos)
```

Here is the *bayesian network with high climbing learned (with restrictions)* :

```
>whitelist <- matrix(c("viento", "lluvia","tormenta","granizo","nieve","nieveSuelo"), 
                ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to")))

>blacklist <- matrix(c("neblina", "granizo","granizo","neblina","niebla","tormenta","tormenta","niebla"), 
                    ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to")))
>learn_hc <- hc(datos, whitelist = whitelist, blacklist = blacklist)
```

---

I need to estimate the **score dispersion obtained through hill climbing** with and without restrictions, **using the leave one out method on my dataset**.

I have no idea how can I do LOOCV with bayesian networks on a specified dataset

I would appreciate your help.

R language